# Python data scraper wikipedia protection policy

Tags: python

When running this I get the following error (below). I believe it is a wiki protection feature. How do i over come this. I am basically trying to scrape the wiki page and search for links with in the code. I apologize for my terrible code or if I have made any terrible errors? I am new to python and lot of it is chopped and copy and pasted.

```
>     > Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>     > "C:\Users\MICHAEL\Desktop\Project X\dataprod.py", line 51, in <module>
>     >     page = urlopen(pg)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
>     >     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 511, in open
>     >     req = Request(fullurl, data)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 329, in __init__
>     >     self.full_url = url   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 355, in full_url
>     >     self._parse()   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 384, in _parse
>     >     raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url) ValueError: unknown url type: '/wiki/Wikipedia:Protection_policy#semi'
```

. Code below:

```
##DataFile. Access info -> Store Info
import shelve

#Saving data in raw txt format
f = open("data.txt", 'w')
print("...")

from urllib.request import urlopen

###############
#Data Scraping#
###############

#Importing relevant librarys
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import httplib2
import warnings
import requests
import contextlib

#Specifying URL(s)

quote_page = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog'

#
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
response = requests.get(quote_page, verify=False)
response.status_code
#
http = httplib2.Http()
status, response = http.request(quote_page)

quotes = []
for link in BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser', parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        quotes.append(link['href'])
#        print(link['href'])

#for loop
info = []
for pg in quotes:

#querying the page and pulling html format
    page = urlopen(pg)

#store and convert using BeautifulSoup into 'soup'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

#Take out the <div> attribrute
    name_box = soup.find('html')

#Take data using by taking 'text'
    name = name_box.text.strip()

#data info Extra
    info.append((name))

#Displaying data grabbed
    print("PULLED DATA                                         .")

#Saving data as CSV
import csv
from datetime import datetime

# open a csv file with append, so old data will not be erased
with open("index.csv", 'a', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

#for loop
    for name in info:
        writer.writerow([name])
f.write(name)
print(f, name)


Exit=input("Press '1' to save and close: ")

if Exit == 1:
    f.close()
    exit()
```

Comment: Python comes with IDLE that allows for easy interactive job. Did you control the return value of `http.request(quote_page)`? Did it download the proper page or a warning message?

Comment: Still new to this and I have no idea where to start on that one

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a user agent in your request, that identify your script as a bot https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy . Please change

```
response = requests.get(quote_page, verify=False, headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'})
```

Try in this way:

```
##DataFile. Access info -> Store Info
import shelve

#Saving data in raw txt format
f = open("data.txt", 'w')
print("...")


###############
#Data Scraping#
###############

#Importing relevant librarys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import warnings
import requests
import contextlib

#Specifying URL(s)

quote_page = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog'

#
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
response = requests.get(quote_page , verify=False, headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'})
status = response.status_code
#


quotes = []
linkL = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
for link in linkL.find_all("a"):
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        quotes.append(link['href'])
#        print(link['href'])

#for loop
info = []
for pg in quotes:

#querying the page and pulling html format
    page = requests.get(pg, verify=False, headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'}))

#store and convert using BeautifulSoup into 'soup'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

#Take out the <div> attribrute
    name_box = soup.find('html')

#Take data using by taking 'text'
    name = name_box.text.strip()

#data info Extra
    info.append((name))

#Displaying data grabbed
    print("PULLED DATA                                         .")

#Saving data as CSV
import csv
from datetime import datetime

# open a csv file with append, so old data will not be erased
with open("index.csv", 'a', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

#for loop
    for name in info:
        writer.writerow([name])
f.write(name)
print(f, name)


Exit=input("Press '1' to save and close: ")

if Exit == 1:
    f.close()
    exit()
```

Comment: I get this error 'ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)'

Comment: at this line status, response = http.request(quote_page) ? Or where?

Comment: I get this error now 'TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'

Comment: you need to include the line where this problem appears

Comment: My apologies: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MICHAEL\Desktop\Project Y\Test.py", line 25, in <module>
    response = requests.get(quote_pageverify=False, headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'})
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'"

Comment: you need to insert a comma: quote_page , verify=False,

Comment: could you print your response.content var ?

Comment: It is the html of the page. Too big to put into paste bin

Comment: perfect, it is ok. could you print pg variable?

Comment: I cant reach the pg variable. Line 41 is where the error is occurring

Comment: https://pastebin.com/rUbpiRXa <-- Another error regarding No connection adapters were found for wikipedia protection policy